# Is there an existing similarity measure for comparing sequences similar to this one?

Tags: algorithms

I work with elements that have a representation in two different vector spaces and I would like to compute an indicator of how similar the neighbors of the elements are in these two spaces.

To do so, I start by computing the list of the $n$-nearest neighbors of all elements, then  I use a sequence similarity measure that, given two sequences, return a score between 0 and 1.

For now I used :

- a [Damerau-Levenshtien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) based similarity measure
- a [Kendall tau distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) based similarity measure

I would like to use a distance that take neighbors order into account and that gives more weight to firsts neighbors since they are more significant.

I have thought about the following similarity measure that appears to deals with both these properties but I can not find it anywhere so I wonder if someone have heard of such similarity measure :

Given to sequences $ a = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, ..., b_n)$ I define the similarity $S(a,b)$ as :

$$S(a,b) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{|(\{a_i | i \in [1,k]\} \cap \{b_i | i \in [1,k]\}|}{k}$$

Some examples :

For $a = b = (1, 2, 3, 4)$ :
$$S(a, b) = \frac{1}{4} \times \left( \frac{1}{1} + \frac{2}{2} + \frac{3}{3} + \frac{4}{4}\right) = 1$$

For $a = (1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $b = (9, 8, 7, 6)$ :
$$S(a, b) = \frac{1}{4} \times \left( \frac{0}{1} + \frac{0}{2} + \frac{0}{3} + \frac{0}{4}\right) = 0$$

For $a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$ and $b = (2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5)$ :
$$S(a, b) = \frac{1}{6} \times \left( \frac{0}{1} + \frac{2}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{4} + \frac{4}{5} + \frac{6}{6} \right)$$

Thus :

- if $a = b$, $S(a,b) = 1$
- if $\{a_i | i \in [1,n]\} \cap \{b_i | i \in [1,n]\} = \emptyset$, $S(a,b) = 0$

Does anyone have heard of such similarity measure between sequences ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two sequences $ a = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, ..., b_n)$ you define the similarity $S(a,b)$ as :

$$S
(a,b) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{|(\{a_i | i \in [1,k]\} \cap \{b_i | i \in [1,k]\}|}{k}.
$$

If instead you had

$$S(a,b) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{|(\{a_i | i \in [1,k]\} \cap \{b_i | i \in [1,k]\}|}{| \{a_i | i \in [1,k]\} \cup \{b_i | i \in [1,k]\}  |}$$
this would be the arithmetic mean of partial *Jaccard distances* on the first $k$ symbols as $k$ varies from $1$ to $n.$

So you chose to normalize by $k$ instead of the union. In some cases people normalize Jaccard by the maximum of the two set sizes, namely
$$\max(|(\{a_i | i \in [1,k]\}|, |\{a_i | i \in [1,k]\}|)$$
but you have chosen to normalize by the maximum possible value of the two set sizes which is $k$ when all symbols in the partial sequence are distinct.

I haven't found anything else at a quick look over the book *Dictionary of Distances* by Deza and Deza.